# Tkinter weird scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to do a little script that has two listboxes with their respective scrollbars. But the scrollbars are acting weird. Consider the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
  def __init__(self, master):

    self.mylist = Listbox(master, height = 30)
    self.mylist.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    for i in range(200):
      self.mylist.insert(END, str(i))

    self.scroll = Scrollbar(master)
    self.scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N + S)

    self.mylist.command = self.scroll.set
    self.scroll.config(command = self.mylist.yview)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

On my pc the scrollbar doesn't go until the end, when it's somewhere below the middle the listbox reaches the end of the content. And when you reach a certain point the scrollbar comes back to the beginning.

Why am I getting this strange behavior?

Comment: Thanks fhdrsdg for correcting my question, as English is not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't couple the Listbox and the Scrollbar right. Instead of

```
self.mylist.command = self.scroll.set
```

use

```
self.mylist.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
```

Comment: Yay!! It worked! The tutorial I followed was broken. Thanks so much for the fast answer!